# Emgu CV video playing is slow?

Tags: c#, visual-studio, opencv, video-processing, emgucv

i am trying to open a video file from disk and try to play it using openCV wrapper: Emgu CV in visual studio c#. i'm using imagebox provided by Emgu CV to show my video on a form. i calculate waiting time for showing next frame of video using this code:

```
await Task.Delay(Convert.ToInt32( 1000.0 / FPS));
```

problem is the video plays slower than calculated formula.
i open a 29.97 FPS video file and the formula should return (1000/30)=33. but when i play the video i can immediately see the video is playing slower than 33 FPS. if i go to my imagebox properties by right clicking on the imagebox , it says that the FPS is 21 which i guess is the actual FPS video is playing.
what is happening?

this is my code. it's very basic:

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{

    VideoCapture videoCapture;
    double FPS;
    double totalFrames;
    int currentFrameNo;

    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void btnOpen_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        OpenFileDialog ofd = new OpenFileDialog();
        if (ofd.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
        {
            videoCapture = new VideoCapture(ofd.FileName);
            FPS = videoCapture.GetCaptureProperty(Emgu.CV.CvEnum.CapProp.Fps);
            totalFrames = videoCapture.GetCaptureProperty(Emgu.CV.CvEnum.CapProp.FrameCount);
            currentFrameNo = 0;
        }
    }

    private async void btnPlay_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        while (currentFrameNo<totalFrames)
        {
            imageBox1.Image = videoCapture.QueryFrame();
            currentFrameNo += 1;
            await Task.Delay(Convert.ToInt32( 1000.0 / FPS));
        }
    }
}
```

what i want is a smooth playing. what should change?
and sorry for the bad language.

Comment: Common mistake. The rest of the loop (e.g decoding the next frame from the video) also takes some time, so you end up delaying to for long.

Comment: this is how everybody suggested. emgu cv example use Thread.sleep((int)(1000.0/fps)) . but that doesnt work for me. it just stops and do nothing. is there a beter way to do this?

Comment: The issue is not in the method of waiting, it's in the duration of the wait, and so far you have not addressed that. Example: If you have to do a 10 minute task every 60 minutes, you can't do the task and then wait 60 minutes. You need to wait 60 - 10 = 50 minutes. | Additionally, let's say something distracts you and at one point you end up waiting 52 minutes. To get back in sync, next time you're waiting, you will have to correct for that, and wait only 48 minutes.

Comment: ok. i see.so this time is not always the same. so how does any video player handles this ? what is the solution. any reference ,book or something ?

Comment: remember that QueryFrame method is consuming time too. additionally if you set the imagebox's size mode to "strectchimage" or if you resizing the frame it will take some time too.

Answer (score 1):

As other comments have suggested - the problem is that a constant delay is being added to whatever the loop processing time is.

A better solution would be to use a Timer (roughly!) as follows:

```
bool playingVideo = false;
Timer frameTimer = new Timer(this.GrabFrame, null, 0, 1000 / 33);

private void btnPlay_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    playingVideo = true;
}


private void GrabFrame(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if(playingVideo)
    {
        while (currentFrameNo<totalFrames)
        {
            imageBox1.Image = videoCapture.QueryFrame();
            currentFrameNo += 1;
        }
    }
}
```

This way the frames will be requested every 33ms regardless of the capture time